# Create a context group in C# to bind several operations into one

Tags: c#, algorithm

I need to spawn individual actions that are not aware of each other but can be grouped into something like an execution group. The individual actions are also cascaded so that there is also more than one hierarchy level.

I can only show a small example to make things a bit clearer and open this example as a starting point for discussions.The example does not make complete sense, but it is to show what my intentions are.

In the example I want to start several algorithms that spawn other algorithms. Before I encapsulate the algorithms in an some sort of a context that binds all algorithms that were allocated in this context and adds them to the list of this context. At a certain time it could happen that someone wants to terminate all algorithms the Terminate() method can be called which calls the Termimnate() method on all algorithms in that context. Of course to make this work the algorithms need knowledge of the AlgorithmContext structure.

Another question is how do I transport the AlgorithmContext to the next thread or task? It also need to be threadsafe.

In the case of this example you can argue that I could hand over the CancellationToken down in the hierarchy of the algorithms but please keep in mind this is only an example. If was thinking in the direction of an ExecutionContext but maybe there are better approaches?

```
public class Algorithm
{
    public readonly AlgorithmContext Context;
    public Algorithm()
    {
        Context = AlgorithmContext.Current;
    }

    public void Terminate() { }
}

public class SmoothImage : Algorithm { }
public class SharpenImage : Algorithm { }

public class Example
{
    public void Process(float[] imagedata)
    {
        // Everyone below should see the AlgorithmContext.Current until the end of the using.
        // No one shall be able to interfere the Current inside the braces for example if another
        // thread creates another instance of AlgorithmContext.
        var Task1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // The AlgorithmContext.Current shall be Context 1 until the end of the using braces.
            using (var ctx = new AlgorithmContext("Context 1"))
            {
                CancellationTokenSource ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
                ct.Token.Register(() => ctx.Terminate());

                SmoothImage smoothImage = new SmoothImage();
                SharpenImage sharpenImage = new SharpenImage();
            }
        });


        var Task2 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // The AlgorithmContext.Current shall be Context 2 until the end of the using braces.
            using (var ctx = new AlgorithmContext("Context 2"))
            {
                CancellationTokenSource ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
                ct.Token.Register(() => ctx.Terminate());

                SmoothImage smoothImage = new SmoothImage();
                SharpenImage sharpenImage = new SharpenImage();
            }
        });

        var Task3 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // The AlgorithmContext.Current shall be Context 2 until the end of the using braces.
            using (var ctx = new AlgorithmContext("Context 3"))
            {
                var Task4 = Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        // The AlgorithmContext.Current shall be Context 3 
                        CancellationTokenSource ct = new CancellationTokenSource();
                        ct.Token.Register(() => ctx.Terminate());

                        SmoothImage smoothImage = new SmoothImage();
                        SharpenImage sharpenImage = new SharpenImage();
                    });
            }
        });


        // There is no current context outside here at all times.
        Task.WaitAll(Task1, Task2, Task3);
    }
}

public class AlgorithmContext : IDisposable
{
    List<Algorithm> Algorithms = new List<Algorithm>();
    public readonly string Name;

    [ThreadStatic]
    public static AlgorithmContext Current;

    public AlgorithmContext(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Current = this;
    }

    public void Add(Algorithm algorithm) { Algorithms.Add(algorithm); }

    public void Terminate()
    {
        foreach (var algo in Algorithms) algo.Terminate();
        Algorithms.Clear();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Current = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to use some wrong terminology which with unclear task and example imposes more confusion. Algorithms cannot be spawn unless you're inventing them on fly. Algorithm is compile time conception while you're most likely talking about some computational pieces which fit into TPL task model considering that tasks may have attached child tasks. So question is why cannot you use simple TPL tasks ?

Comment: For me it seems like you are overcomplicating it. There is already a mechanism for algorithms to call other algorithms and it is called "code". All you need is probably just to spawn asynchronous tasks to execute some CPU-bound code, and then stop them at some point with `CancellationTokenSource`. It seems like `AlgorithmContext` is useless in this scenario, but may be I just don't understand your scenario in a whole. Try to tell more why you want this and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: As Dmytro explained, by using the wrong terminology you make it a lot harder to understand what you want. It could be you are looking for something like Parallel.ForEach or PLINQ. Or a TPL Dataflow pipeline, with one TransformBlock smoothing images and another sharpening them. Or?

Comment: If one replaces `Process` with `Pipeline` and `Algorithm` with `Block` this looks like an attempt to create a dataflow pipeline. Which already handles continuations, cancellations, backpressure, buffering etc

Comment: I have extended the example a bit. I'm not discussing an image processing concept alone, and I already tried the DataFlow pipeline. It has a lot of drawbacks with restarting and resuming. But nevertheless it's not about cancellation only. Its also about having a global concept, also for example to track allocated memory, status information, etc. With the example above I think my question is answered, but I was hoping there is already some mechanism that .NET supports.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's not as complicated as you described.
You need a context for multiple algorithm. One of the main jobs of this context is to handle termination of algorithms.
So, you need events! I rewrite your entire sample code.

```
public abstract class Algorithm
{
    protected readonly AlgorithmContext _context;

    public Algorithm(AlgorithmContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _context.Terminated += (sender, e) =>
        {

            Terminate();
        };

    }

    public abstract void Terminate();
}

public class SmoothImage : Algorithm
{
    public SmoothImage(AlgorithmContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override void Terminate()
    {
        // do whatever you want
    }
}

public class SharpenImage : Algorithm
{
    public SharpenImage(AlgorithmContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override void Terminate()
    {
        // do whatever you want
    }
}

public class Example
{
    public void Process(float[] imagedata)
    {
        var Task1 = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var ctx = new AlgorithmContext("Context 1"))
            {
                SmoothImage smoothImage = new SmoothImage(ctx);
                SharpenImage sharpenImage = new SharpenImage(ctx);
            }
        });

        // ...
        Task.WaitAll(Task1, Task2, Task3);
    }
}

public class AlgorithmContext : IDisposable
{
    public AlgorithmContext(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public event EventHandler Terminated;
    public string Name { get; }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Terminate();
    }

    public void Terminate()
    {
        Terminated?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

As you said, because algorithms are not aware of each other, so maybe they don't need to be in context.

If you need to terminate every other algorithms within a context, so just call `_context.Terminate()` somewhere in an algorithm

Anyway, hope it helps